# Angular watch does not trigger on certain objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, promise

The following problem: When creating an element directive that is watching an attribute, the watch does not trigger if the watched expression resolves to a promise (using Kris Kowal's Q library). JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Netaork/PjS8J/

Snippet:

```
var module = angular.module("my-module", []);

angular.module('my-module').directive('promise', function ($compile) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {

            // watch variant 1, watching the expression directly
            scope.$watch(iAttrs['use'], function(newValue, oldValue) {
               console.log('1.)', newValue, oldValue); 
            });

            // watch variant 2, using a function and $eval to evaluate the expression
            scope.$watch(function(scope) {
                return scope.$eval(iAttrs['use']);
            }, function(newValue, oldValue) {
               console.log('2.)', newValue, oldValue); 
            });

            // watch variant 3, using a function and return watched expression, this
            // works only for atomar expressions, but is the only one to trigger if
            // the expression resolves to a promise
            scope.$watch(function(scope) {
                return scope[iAttrs['use']];   
            }, function(newValue, oldValue) {
               console.log('3.)', newValue, oldValue); 
            });
        },
        restrict: 'E'
    };
});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    var promise = Q.defer().promise;
    //promise = { a: 'Hello World', b: 1337 };

    $scope.pr = promise;
    $scope.getPr = function() {
        return promise;   
    }
}
```

The HTML looks simple:

```
<div ng-app="my-module">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <promise use="getPr()"></promise>
        <promise use="pr"></promise>
    </div>
</div>
```

The first promise element triggers only watch 1 and 2 with the promise. Watch 3 can obviously not be resolved as the syntax is already wrong. So here is everything as expected.

The second promise element shows triggers only watch 3, which is unexpected.

If you uncomment the line in the controller to exchange the promise with a standard object, everything triggers as expected.

Do I miss something here? Angular docs says that it uses [angular.equals](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.equals) to test changing objects. If I test my promise against undefined it returns true.